# how to resolve the page redirect issue?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have inline vf page.From the inline vf page values after save i have to update some values in detail page.the values are saved .But after clicking the save button in line Vf page it goes some page.

```
Before clicking the save button
```

[image]

```
after clicking the save button
```

[image]

apex code

```
public Pagereference customSave(){

    strop=objService.CodeC2G__c;
    String strQuantity=String.valueof(objService.Quantity__c);
    system.debug('<<<<<selected value in save'+strop+'quanity'+strQuantity);
    strCode=strop.substringbefore('-').trim();
    strLabel =strop.substringafter('-').trim();
    system.debug('<<<<<strCode'+strCode+''+strLabel);
    objService.id=strId;
    objService.Code__c=strCode;
    objService.Label__c=strLabel;
    Double dbPriceHT;
    Rfleet_DZC2GOptionDetails_CLS optionValues =new Rfleet_DZC2GOptionDetails_CLS();     
    mapOptionCodePrice = optionValues.getOptionPrice(strModelCode,strVersionCode);
    if (mapOptionCodePrice.containsKey(strCode)) {
        dbPriceHT = mapOptionCodePrice.get(strCode);
    }
    if (dbPriceHT!=null) {
        objService.Price_HT__c=dbPriceHT;
    }
    List<Service__c> lstService = new List<Service__c>{objService};

    system.debug('<<<<<lst '+lstService );
    string strJSON = JSON.serializePretty(lstService );
    Rfleet_ServiceOption_CLS.updateService(strJSON );
return null;
}
```

vf page

```
<apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!customSave}" />
```

Comment: after click on save button what should happen ?

Comment: It should remain in the same detail page with newly update values

Comment: Uma.. means you want to reload the entire page ? correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest use oncomplete attribute of `apex:command` button

```
<apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!customSave}" 
     oncomplete="window.top.location.href = '/{!parent.Id}'" />
```

instead parent Id pass the your actual object Id (I think service Id)

after click on save it will redirect to service detail page

Answer (score 1):

From the recipe change the save button to apex:commandlink

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
```

to

```
<apex:commandLink value="Save" action="{!save}" target="_parent" 
        styleClass="btn" style="text-decoration:none;padding:4px;">
```

Since commandlink offers a target attribute I make use of it and make the command link exactly like the button using styleclass and style attributes.

It will work for you.